# iOS SSL certificate invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl

I am trying to make a connection to one of my web servers to pull some JSON data down and format it.

i know there used to be away around this to force the device to trust the connection, however those methods have been deprecated by apple The site has a 128bit AES encryption signed by Comodo with an extended validation (so we have the green bar) and this is even recognised by Safari hence I dont understand why Xcode is complaining.

Here is the error I get- pardon the fact i have annotated some parts of the URL out as they contain posted data with raw passwords (for testing).

[image: XCode Error]

[image: SSL Cert]

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say what's going one with only these few information but I suggest you look at the analysis of [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look out for chain issues, i.e. incomplete chains where extra downloads are required.  Desktop browsers can often deal with missing intermediate certificates while other clients don't.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich - the report does say Contains anchor under Chain Issues - what does this mean?

Comment: This means that you have included the root certificate, which you should not. The trusted root has to be on the system and should not be included in the chain, although most clients simply ignore it.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try and rectify this